# Lightning salesforce embed problem

Tags: apex

So I have implemented a script that uses angular as well, however when I use {{1+1}} it does nothing, also it shows me a warning that is created inside the Javascript file(we created it too show that it works).

The code for the lightning static resource is:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
<ltng:require styles="/resource/bootstrap"
              scripts="/resource/BookingWidget,/resource/angular"       
    />

<html aura-ng="BB">
    <body id="bb">
        {{1+1}}     


    </body>
</html>
```

ng-app="" even being empty it should run {{1+1}}

I left it for five minutes and it gave me a warning

"WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once"

Also the Dev console has no errors either meanwhile even though BookingWidget includes angular if I try to include the "BookingWidget" or "angular" file alone it still does not work.

I have read up on aura-ng as well? Would I need this to be able to implement the custom "BookingWidget"?

Comment: Check is that static resource is added correctly?

Comment: its added correctly - it loads everything but angular just refuses to work.